# How do I enable or disable the inclusiveness underlining in outlook office 365?

Tags: office-365, outlook-365

How do I enable or disable the purple underlining for non-inclusive or biased language in Outlook in Office 365? An example message: "inclusiveness: this language may appear biased".

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings > Mail > Compose and Reply > Microsoft Editor Settings found at https://outlook.office.com/mail/options/mail/messageContent and there is a toggle for enabling/disabling "Inclusiveness" in the "Refinements" section.